# Adding new datas to the email

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, phpmailer

The code below checks the "Paid" reservations from the database and sends them as an email with a cron job.

Normally only "pay_url" data is added from the database, yet I'd like to add "customer_name", "customer_surname" and "amount" along with pay_url.

Could you please guide me on how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
include "../lib/include.php";

$yesterdayDate = date("Y-m-d 09:00:00", strtotime("-1 days"));
$query = "select * from links where status = 1 and cc_payment_id != '' and payment_date >= '".$yesterdayDate."' and payment_date <= '".date("Y-m-d 08:59:59")."'";


$q = $db->query($query);
foreach ($q AS $a) {

    $mail_content .= "".$a["pay_url"]." -> Paid<br>";
}

if ($mail_content != "") {
    SendMail($settings["system_email"],$mail_content,"Paid Reservations");
}
```

Comment: Yes @JNevill, pay_url, customer_name, customer_surname, and amount are all columns on the table actually. Could you please write the whole part, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as you did with pay_url. Just add it to the $mail_content variable.
You can simply add

```
foreach ($q AS $a) {
    $mail_content .= "{$a['pay_url']} -> Paid <br>";
    $mail_content .= "Customer's name - {$a['customer_name']} <br>";
    ...
}
```

or make it one variable

```
foreach ($q AS $a) {
    $mail_content = "
        {$a['pay_url']} -> Paid <br>
        Customer's name: {$a['customer_name']}
    ";
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($q AS $a) {
    $mail_content .= "{$a['pay_url']} - {$a['customer_name']} - {$a['customer_surname']} - {$a['amount']} -> Paid <br>";
} ` Will this work since there are approx. 4-5 paid reservations each day?  https://imgur.com/a/baEkQ7s

Comment: it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. It works, so thank you so much!! @Sempoinus